# Android-Save data which is fetched from one project into the sharedPreferences in other project

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

I want to keep all the xml and related java files to be in one android project and business logic in other android project, but in this there will be no xml files. Now I want to save data; say login credentials in to shared preferences, so i should fetch data from 1st project (where i have `login.xml` and `login.java`) and pass to 2nd project (where i have `SharedPreferencesClass.java` in this i read and write data into the shared preferences. But I am getting error in instantiating shared preferences class:

```
SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.
        getDefaultSharedPreferences(LoginActivity.getContext());
```

Comment: have read about library projects. You can have 1 project as a library project and reference the same in another. Since its only java files you can create a jar and import the classes necessary

Comment: I tried this but still I get the runtime error.

Comment: Post the exception - always post the exception if you have one! Stay with default shared preferences

Answer (score 1):

You can have all the business logic in your library project and to access the shared preferences you need the context.So pass the context in the constructor of your classes in library project and use it to fetch shared preferences.

Comment: This also didn't work..I get run time error if I instantiate the SharedPreferences class.

Comment: Try `SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = context.getSharedPreferences("PREFS_PRIVATE", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);`